# Exiting shell functions on error

Tags: linux, function, shell, sh, exit

I need a way to automatically exit a shell function if there is an error while it executes, like `set -e` just for functions.

Is this possible or is the only way is something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
foo() {( set -e;
    # doStuff
)}
# doStuff
foo
# doStuff
```

Comment: Just use `foo() ( ... )` rather than `foo() { ... }` if you want a function to execute in a subshell; there's no need for `foo() { ( ... ) }`.

Comment: ...by the way -- `set -e` is... not exactly considered good practice in the wider world. See, for instance, its listing in http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete, and the caveats in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Comment: http://www.fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Error_handling also has a rather comprehensive explanation of `set -e`'s behavior, likely helpful to anyone tackling this question.

Comment: ...notably, if you were using bash rather than /bin/sh, you could use `set -E`, which *does* work for functions.

Comment: ...in general, though, the best practice is to put `|| return` on the end of each line within a function for which you explicitly want this behavior. Even inasmuch as you may think otherwise, you almost certainly don't want it for all of them (consider, for instance, that `let --i` returns a nonzero exit status when the resulting value of `i` is zero, whereas `let i--` does the same when the *initial* value of `i` was zero; do you really want that to have side effects on flow control?).

Comment: **1**. Thankyou. **2**. I understand but this is what i want. **4**. I just noticed that /bin/sh directs to bash in my computer... . **5**. Yes I want it for all of them.

Comment: @Charles Duffy What do I do with the question? How should I close it?

Comment: Even if `/bin/sh` is a link to bash, bash checks its `argv[0]` -- that is, the name it's started with -- and runs in POSIX mode (`set -o posix`) if started as `sh` rather than `bash`.

Comment: ...as for the question, though, it's a reasonable one; I don't currently see a reason to close it -- you may well get an answer eventually (or someone might find a duplicate and start a vote-to-close at that time, but that would get you an answer too).